# the recursion of custom data type

Tags: haskell

I am a quite newbie of haskell.
I am quite not sure of recursion of string.

I made something simple example.

```
 data P = P String deriving (Show,Eq,Read)
 data F = F [String] deriving (Show,Eq,Read)

 checkout :: [P] -> F
 checkout [] = F [""]
 checkout (x:xs) = getname x where
     getname (P ame) = F [ame ]
     -- getname (P ame) = F [ame :(getname xs)] I tried like this but it is an error...
```

Main> checkout[(P "S"), (P "WW")] --> F["S"]

How can I get  F["S", "WW"] ??

One more question >

```
data P = P String Int deriving (Show,Eq,Read)
data F = F [String] [Int] deriving (Show,Eq,Read)

checkout :: [P] -> F
checkout xs = F (removePs xs)
checkout xs = F [ str | (P str _ ) <- xs ]
checkout xs = U [ o | (P _ o ) <- xs ]
```

I have got redundant , is there any way to solve?

Comment: First, try creating a function of type `[P] -> [String]`, then you can pass the result to the `F` constructor.

Comment: what if I create [P] -> [String] function, the input data type turn into be [String] so, [String] -> F ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can build a function `P -> String`, which simply "removes" the `P` constructor

```
removeP :: P -> String
removeP (P str) = str
```

Then, you can apply that on a list

```
removePs :: [P] -> [String]
removePs xs = map removeP xs
```

Finally, we can exploit the constructor `F :: [String] -> F` as follows

```
checkout :: [P] -> F
checkout xs = F (removePs xs)
```

Alternatively, we could have used a list comprehension:

```
checkout xs = F [ str | (P str) <- xs ]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , I tried to modify something , but I have got redundant warning, would you please see answer it - I just edited my question

Comment: @user9375305 If you want to use a list comprehension, you only need the line `checkout xs = F [ str | (P str) <- xs ]` after the type signature, nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to simply upgrade your `getname` function to take in lists using `map`:

```
checkout :: [P] -> [F]
checkout xs = map getname xs where
  getname (P name) = F [name]
```

But if you really want to explicitly recurse, we can just do the same thing the implementation of [`map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#map) does:

```
checkout :: [P] -> [F]
checkout [] = []
checkout (x:xs) = (getname x : checkout xs) where
  getname (P name) = F [name]
```

Comment: @user9375305 You could certainly have that as well (using tagged unions) but... I don't think you want that from your example.